# A way to use pathfinding in 3D without raycasts and for mulitple targets

Tags: c++, algorithm, graphics, directx, path-finding

I'm currently making a game in the DirectX engine in c++. I'm using path-finding to guide an army of soldiers to a specific location. the problem is that I use raycasts to see if there is nothing in the way of my path, and this slows down the speed of the game. Is there a better way to do pathfinding?

I also have a problem with the moving of my army. Right now i'm using the average of soldiers' positions as the start point, which means all the soldiers need to go there first before moving to the end point. Is there a way to make them go to the end point without going to the startpoint?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: More detail would help.  It sounds like you're using 3D raycasts to find a 2D ground paths for your soldiers; is this true?  How detailed does your navigation model need to be?  How large a region are you doing pathfinding over?  Also, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like A-Star? to navigate via nodes, or some sort of 2d-array representation of your map? written good it could possible be faster aswell as easier to do with jobs ( multithreaded ).

if you have a solider, who is at postion A, and needs to get to B.
just calulate the path from C(the avrage position what ever) to B. get the direction from a to b and do some sort of interpolation. ( havent done this, or tried it, but it could probablt work out pretty well!)

Answer (score 0):

Are you hit-testing every object when you are raycasting?

That can be very expensive when you have many objects and soldiers.
A common solution is to divide your world into square grid cells, and put each object in a list of objects for that grid.

Then you draw an imaginary line from the soldier to the destination and check each cell what objects you need to hit test against. This way you will evaluate only objects close to the straight path and ignore all others.